split ISP to two separate home routers
My router handles 50 items. I have 72 and counting.
I thought I could split my 10Gb signal to two routers. Then use one for smart devices tv, phone, pc, tablets and one for dumb devices; light switches, bulbs, cameras, motion sensors etc.
Each router would then have less than 50 devices to handle.
Would that work better than one (tp-link ax11000) router with 70 plus devices. And what would the speeds be 5Gb each or 10Gb each?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

How did you determine that your router only supports 50 devices?
